# How to get the value from Custom Annotation in my advice method in Spring AOP?

Tags: spring-boot, annotations, aop, spring-aop, spring-annotations

I have my custom annotation like this:

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface CutomAnnotation{
    String value() default "";
}
```

My aspect class looks like this:

```java
@Aspect
@Component
public class MyCustomAspect{

@Around("@annotation(com.forceframework.web.handlers.monitoring.MeterRegTimer)")
public Object aroundJoinPoint(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable{
    System.out.println("Timer started: "+joinPoint.getSignature());
    Object objToReturn=joinPoint.proceed();
    System.out.println("Timer ended: "+joinPoint.getSignature());
    return objToReturn;
    }
}
```

The place I use the annotation in a controller class:

```java
@CustomAnnotation(value="timer")
@GetMapping(value="/test")
public ResponseEntity test() {}
```

I would like to know can I access the `value` passed from my `CustomAnnotation` in the around advice method `aroundJoinPoint` in `MyCustomAspect` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();
    Method method = signature.getMethod();
    CutomAnnotation methodAnnotation = method.getDeclaredAnnotation(CutomAnnotation.class);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your advice should be declared as shown below:

```java
@Around("@annotation(customAnnotationArgumentName)")
public Object aroundJoinPoint(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, CustomAnnotation customAnnotationArgumentName) throws Throwable {
// ...
}
```

See [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop) for more info.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, not the one by _milkdove_. Binding an annotation to an advice method argument is the canonical and most elegant way to do that, not using reflection.